# Isekai manga where the main character has an SSR skill to gain more skill

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm searching for a manga where a lot of people are sent to another world, and dispatched to a village with a number. Everyone has a skill, but the main character has a Super Supreme Rare (SSR) skill and he can absorb other skills and attributes. I recall that in some chapters, the village he was in had to compete for resources with another village.